# php flexible path combine for urls

Tags: php

I have a baseurl (e.g. http://google.at)
and a path (e.g. search/user)

How can I combine both to http://google.at/search/user

and make sure it also works if the baseurl is http://google.at/ so it wouldn't produce http://google.at//search/user 
I do not want to manually perform string checks/manipulations, but I am rather looking for a function like path_combine

Comment: Why not make a new path_combine_me function? Is there something that would make that not work, like many different URLs?

Comment: @Grim... I was just wondering if there is a native way to do this in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
function path_combine($base, $path) {
  return rtrim($base, '/') . '/' . $path;
}

var_dump(
  path_combine('http://google.at', 'search/user'),
  path_combine('http://google.at/', 'search/user')
);

// output:
// string(28) "http://google.at/search/user"
// string(28) "http://google.at/search/user"
```

(If you want flexibility on whether the path has a leading slash or not as well, then add an `ltrim` accordingly.)